# Filter table by if cell contains value of cell in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have Tabel1 in Sheet1 that contains information with production Buckets. An example of a bucket number would be "**APG-1710**-072621-**A3**" where "072621" is the date, and the bolded parts change.

I have the date in the format mmddyy in cell A2 in a sheet called StandardWork "=Today()"

How can I filter Table1 by the date when it is a part of the data in a cell?

My attempt:

```
Sub Filter_Bucket()

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = StandardWork.Range("A2").Value Then
       Sheet1.Range("Table1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=StandardWork.Range("A2").Value
   End If

End Sub
```

Please advised if I am going in the wrong direction, and tell me what you would do in this situation.

Comment: Can you add a new column to your table and use MID function to retrieve only the date and then you can filter it by the column just created?

Comment: I've created a new column with just the date using the MID function like you suggested. I am now trying the following code:                                                        
`Sub BucketFilter()

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").AutoFilter Field:=3, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic, Criteria1:=xlFilterToday

End Sub` But when I run the code it filters out all of the tables values

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Advanced Filters, you need to have a  criteria. Because I don't know where  you created the criteria, I am creating it with the code and after filtering it is cleared.

This is the dummy 'table'

[image]

Place this code in the sheet module 'StandardWork'

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing And IsDate(Range("A2")) Then
        ' Transform date to a string
        Dim vDate As String: vDate = CStr(Format(Target.Value, "mmddyy"))
        
        ' Create  the criteria
        Sheet1.Range("D1").Value = "myDate"
        Sheet1.Range("D2").Value = vDate
        
        ' Filter data on sheet1
        Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
            CriteriaRange:=Sheet1.Range("D1:D2")
            
        ' Clear the criteria
        Sheet1.Range("D1:D2").ClearContents
   End If
End Sub
```